# Number of cuts in a graph

Tags: graph-theory

How many cuts does a graph with n vertices have?

The first answer would be 2^n. Then one must substract the 2 cases where one of the sets is empty,hence the answer is 2^n - 2.

My question is: why must we substract the 2 cases? Neither Cormen nor Wiki says that the 2 sets must be non-empty. Can't we also have these cases,whose cut-sets are empty?

Comment: what is a cut? If it is a subset $S \subset V$ such that the induced subgraph on $V \setminus S$ is disconnected then your numbers are not right. Take $K_n$ what is a cut here?

Comment: A cut C=(S,T) is a partition of V of a graph G=(V,E) into two subsets S and T. The cut-set of a cut C=(S,T) is the set {(u,v) in E | u in S, v  in T} of edges that have one endpoint in S and the other endpoint in T.

Comment: That sounds strange! Where is this cut defined, any reference?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_(graph_theory)
And also in Cormen,at the Graph chapter.

Comment: Right! Then the answer should be $2^{n-1}$. As the cut $A \cup B=V$ is same as $B \cup A =V$ and we allow empty, $V$ as a cut.

Comment: Hmm,let's see. Are empty sets allowed or not? In a topic here,I read that they are not.

Comment: Moreover,what you said earlier,A∪B=V is same as B∪A=V. I don't think it stands for directed graphs.

Comment: If empty sets are not allowed then it's juts one less!

Comment: Well directed or not the definition of the cut does not care much about the graph, it is just a partition of a set into two disjoint subsets that's all according to wiki!

Comment: But then there's "The cut-set of a cut C=(S,T) is the set {(u,v) in E | u in S, v in T} of edges that have one endpoint in S and the other endpoint in T." , which states a difference between S and T,hence between the cut (S,T) and (T,S),in my opinion.

Comment: The cut set is a set of edges that you may attach to a cut, it does not impose a condition on a cut!

Comment: Here's a link that briefly explains something http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005162/why-does-a-graph-with-n-vertices-have-2n-2-cuts
They substract the 2 empty-sets,though.

Comment: I see A cut is an ordered pair so the answer is $2^n$ but the definition allows empty cuts.

Comment: According to that topic,empty sets are not allowed,hence 2^n -2.
The definitions I've seen in Cormen and Wiki didn't say anything about them. Have you found any where empty sets are allowed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33725/discussion-between-baharampuri-and-flaviumanica).

Answer (score 3):

The answers in the comments above are rigth to the order of magnitude. The cut of a graph is defined as a partition of a graph's G = (V, E) vertices set V into two disjoint nonempty subsets. 
Then, the number of cuts may counted as: $ 2^{n-1} $ - number of ways to form  one subset of the cut (we choose one vertex to be in another cut by default). And then you should subtract 1 to exclude the case when an empty set was obtained (all vertices happened to be in another cut). And the final answer is $$ 2^{n-1}-1$$
Indeed, lets substitute in formula for graphs vith $card(V) = n$: $$ n= 2: 2^{2-1} - 1= 1$$
$$ n = 3: 2^{3-1}-1 = 3$$
$$ n = 4: 2^{4-1}-1 = 7$$

Comment: almost a year after, though.